# Error in mysql query with IF statement and sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have (for me at least) a complex query that I build with examples from this site. The last thing I added was the  `IF` statement. Without the IF statement it was working with the TRUE part of the IF statement. I hope you girls/guys can help me out here. This is the query :

```
SELECT 
    t.ID, t.start_time, t.end_time, t.start_date, t.end_date, t.balance, 
    u1.first_name AS teacher_one_first_name, u1.last_name AS teacher_one_last_name, 
    u2.first_name AS teacher_two_first_name, u2.last_name AS teacher_two_last_name,
    company.name, company.post_city, tag, lvl,
    IF(
        t.balance=1,
        (
            (SELECT count(user_ID)
                FROM company_lesson_block_student
                WHERE lead_follow=0 AND company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID) AS lead,
            (SELECT count(user_ID)
                FROM company_lesson_block_student
                WHERE lead_follow=1 AND company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID) AS follow
        ),
            (SELECT count(user_ID)
                FROM company_lesson_block_student
                WHERE company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID) AS total_student
    )
    FROM company_lesson_block AS t
    LEFT JOIN company_lvl ON company_lvl.ID = t.lvl_ID
    LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.ID = t.style_ID
    LEFT JOIN company ON company.ID=t.location_ID
    LEFT JOIN user AS u1 ON t.teacher_one_ID=u1.ID
    LEFT JOIN user AS u2 ON t.teacher_two_ID=u2.ID
    WHERE t.company_ID='1' AND location_ID='1' AND company_season_ID='1'
    ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

The error message i get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
>   for the right syntax to use near 'AS lead, (SELECT count(user_ID) FROM company_less' at line 10

Any help/tips are appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return 2 columns, but `IF` can return only 1, so you need 2 `IF`s:

```
........................
IF(
    t.balance=1,
        (SELECT count(user_ID)
            FROM company_lesson_block_student
            WHERE lead_follow=0 AND company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID),
        (SELECT count(user_ID)
            FROM company_lesson_block_student
            WHERE company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID)
) AS ????,
IF(
    t.balance=1,
       (SELECT count(user_ID)
            FROM company_lesson_block_student
            WHERE lead_follow=1 AND company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID),
        (SELECT count(user_ID)
            FROM company_lesson_block_student
            WHERE company_lesson_block_ID=t.ID)
) AS ????
........................
```

You must set the aliases after the closing parenthesis of `IF`. 
Maybe you must rethink this logic because in case of `FALSE`, the same value is returned twice.

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew that. I indeed must recheck my logic with this new information